# How to query RunTestsResult Class

Tags: apex, failing-tests

Can we query "RunTestsResult" class to get all the failed class.
I queried this class in developer console but it was not returning any value.

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: Select stacktrace, message from ApexTestResult

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper did your error solved.

Comment: @TusharSharma yes now my error is solved, I'm able to query without using tooling api, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I test your query and it works fine for me. Select the checkbox `Use Tooling API` to get the result.
[image]

PS: If you see blank rows then scroll down and you will see all test classes which fails.

Comment: Even after selecting tooling API it's not working

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper check two points first is there any test class actually failing? second you are getting 0 results or some records?